# Summing up values from string (componentsJoinedByString)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, sum, entity-attribute-value

Simple question, i think...

How can I add up the values in the following string? `scoreValue = "8.68,2.815,5,7.975,2.695,7.285,3.625,7.36,8.335,2.485";`

Bit of background info. The string is returned from a CoreData entity (called "ScoreData"), and put into an instance of NSDictionary, like this:

```
NSDictionary *getScoreValues = [self.scoreEntityResultsForValues objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSLog(@"getScoreValues returns: %@", getScoreValues); // This is what getScoreValues returns for each of the scoreValue's in the CoreData entity.
```

This is how the value's are posted to the entity initially

```
//Call the ScoreData entity
ScoreData *newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ScoreData" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

//Join the value returned from the NSArray by a "," and post them as a string to the ScoreData entity
NSString *stringForScoreEntity = [[CEWStoreVars sharedScoreArray].sharedScoreArrayProperty componentsJoinedByString:@","];
newEntry.scoreValue = stringForScoreEntity;
```

The reason I post the values as a string to the entity, is because I couldn't get the entity to accept a float value, and I want to be able to pull out each seperate score later on. But I'm open to suggestions if there is a better method of doing this. Also, let me know if you need more code to decipher what's going on!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

For anyone interested, this is how the code should look:

```
//Load the Key and KeyValue into Dictionary
NSDictionary *getScoreValues = [self.scoreEntityResultsForValues objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

//Convert the dictionary keyValue to a string
NSString *convertDictKeyToString  = [getScoreValues objectForKey:@"scoreValue"];

//Remove the "," in the string.
NSArray *items = [convertDictKeyToString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

//Add them up to get the sum
double total = 0.0;
for (NSString *string in items)
{
    total += [string floatValue];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *items = [scoreValue componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; //scoreValue is a string

double total = 0.0;
for (NSString *string in items)
{
    total += [string floatValue];
}
```

Comment: that doesnt seem to work. It give me an error: "No visible interface for NSDictionary declares the selector 'componentsSeperatedByString'

Comment: scoreValue should be a NSString no a NSDictionary! From your question: "How can I add up the values in the following string?"